# ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 5527, maximum: 4000)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle10g

I am facing an error related to CLOB to CHAR while running the below query.
The query was huge but I am able to find out the statement that is creating the problem but I am unable to resolve it.
I have tried using DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR but it doesnot work.
A help in this is much appreciated.

```
SELECT
  A.CLIENT_ID,
  a.account_description,
  'Incoming' AS DIRECTION,
  'IncomingSwift 103',
  IMB.REFERENCE_NO,
  IMB.AMOUNT,
  IMB.CCY,
  IMB.VALUE_DATE,
  IMB.PROCESS_STATUS,
  CASE
    WHEN IMB.REPAIR_REASON = 'MS-INVIBAN' AND IMB.SENDER in (select bic_code from Bic_Cb_Clients) THEN 'CB DISTRIBUTION'
    WHEN IMB.REPAIR_REASON = 'MS-INVIBAN' AND to_char(concat(substr( IMB.message,(instr(IMB.message, '57A:')+4),8),'XXX')) in (select bic_code from Bic_Cb_Clients) THEN 'CB COLLECT'
    WHEN IMB.STATUS = 'C' THEN 'Pending Cover Match'
    ELSE IMB.REPAIR_REASON
  END AS REPAIR_REASON,
  k.parameters as ADDITIONAL_INFO,
  /*10 */
  IMB.GENERATED_REF_NO,
  IMB.MAKER_ID,
  IMB.CHECKER_ID,
  IMB.AUTH_STATUS,
  IMB.BRANCH,
  '' AS FILE_REF_NO,
  1,
  case when A.CLIENT_ID is null then null
  else
  NVL(substr(TO_CHAR(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50),
    substr(TO_CHAR(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59F:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59F:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50)) end as   RECEIVER_ACCOUNT,
  IMB.SENDER AS SENDERRECEIVERBIC,
  /* 20 */
  REMARKS,
 case when A.CLIENT_ID is null then null
  else
  NVL(substr(TO_CHAR(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50),
    substr(TO_CHAR(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59F:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59F:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50)) end as   RECEIVER_ACCOUNT,
 CASE WHEN A.CLIENT_ID is NULL then null
 ELSE
  NVL(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(NVL(substr((substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50),
        substr(TO_CHAR(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59F:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59F:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50))),-10,10),
        NVL(substr(TO_CHAR(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50),
    substr(TO_CHAR(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59F:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59F:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50))) END as VA_RECEIVER_ACCOUNT,
  replace(
   NVL(substr(TO_CHAR(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':50F:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':50F:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50),
    substr(TO_CHAR(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':50K:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':50K:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50)) ,'/',''
  ) AS "50K" /*BENEF_INST1 */,
```

regexp_replace(regexp_substr(regexp_substr(TO_CHAR(replace((imb.message), chr(10), '::')), ':59:.*'), '::.*?::.*?::'), '::(.*?)::(.*?)::', '\1') AS BNAME2,
replace(substr(TO_CHAR(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':52A:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':52A:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50),'/','') AS "52A"
FROM
FCUBS.MSTB_DLY_MSG_IN IMB
LEFT JOIN SXPINTERNAL.dm_account a on a.account_iban =
NVL(substr(TO_CHAR(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50),
substr((substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59F:') + 5,instr(substr(imb.message,instr(imb.message,':59F:') + 5,50),CHR(10)) - 1)),1,50))
LEFT JOIN (select m.contract_ref_no, m.parameters, max(m.error_code) as max_error_code from fcubs.cstb_contract_exception m group by m.contract_ref_no, m.parameters) k
on k.contract_ref_no = IMB.dcn
WHERE
PROCESS_STATUS   = 'R'
AND SWIFT_MSG_TYPE = '103'

From above query, the below piece is creating the CLOB to CHAR error:

regexp_replace(regexp_substr(regexp_substr(TO_CHAR(replace((imb.message), chr(10), '::')), ':59:.*'), '::.*?::.*?::'), '::(.*?)::(.*?)::', '\1') AS BNAME2,

Also, I do not have permission to change the parent table, so i cannot increase the CLOB/BLOB value. I have to somehow manage to handle it in the query itself.

Comment: You're getting the error because the CLOB (after you've replaced newlines) is more that 4000 bytes; [the 'to_char()' docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-character.html) say you get an error if the result is too big. Why are you doing that, and what "didn't work" when you used `dbms_lob.substr`? How did you use it, and what happened? Please edit your question to give a [mre], as most of the code seems to be irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your comment. I am using dbms_lob.substr at the start of that statement which i have mentioned as the problem creator. I was making a mistake where I did not remove TO_CHAR after adding dbms_lob.substr. I had to remove to_char as both does the same job except of the fact that for longer strings, we use dbms_lob.substr. By removing the to_char form the statement, I was able to resolve the issue

Comment: what is a [mcve]